# Update existing value of a key in a hash in javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, rating-system

I'm inserting an object in an array with two keys `question_id` and `rating` whenever user clicks a star on front-end. What I'm looking for if user changes the rating of any of the star then update the value of the existing key (if present) otherwise push the entry to the array.

Code sample below

`$scope.yellowPages = [] // is defined`

```
if ($scope.yellowPages.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.yellowPages.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.yellowPages[i]["question_id"] == question_id) {
          $scope.yellowPages[i]["rating"] = rating; // here updating the existing value of key, but what is happening it's updates and as well as creates a new entry with the updated value.
      }
      else{
        $scope.yellowPages.push({rating: rating, question_id: question_id});
      } // if not present
    }
  }
  else{
    $scope.yellowPages.push({rating: rating, question_id: question_id}); // for 1st time
  } 
}
```

My ultimate goal is to have a unique `question_id's` and there `rating`, array should only 5 elements.

Thanks

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: My question is how do I keep only one rating corresponding to 1 particular question_id, Right now what's happening is it's updating the current value as well as it's insert new value as well. I don't want it to insert new value, just update the value corresponding to that particular key if exists or else insert it into the array.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your if/else in the for loop. you are checking if the current element in the forloop iteration is the same question:

```
if ($scope.yellowPages[i]["question_id"] == question_id) {
```

If it is not, you are pushing the item into the array:

```
$scope.yellowPages.push({rating: rating, question_id: question_id});
```

This happens for every iteration of the loop. So for example if you have 3 items in the array, and the matching question id is the third item, you will push a new object ($scope.yellowPages.push({rating: rating, question_id: question_id});) into the array twice before reaching the matching object in the third index and updating its rating.

Comment: I think you are right Ken, but how do I fix it then, any suggestion ?

Comment: @VibhooMishra Instead of having the else statement in the foreach loop, you could use a boolean value set to false before the foreach loop. Then inside the foreach loop, if the question is found, set the boolean value to true. Then after the foreach loop, check if the question was found, and if it was not, push the question into your array.

Here is some updated code as an example, https://pastebin.com/1vh9YwDD

Edit: updated with pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an array? Instead use an object that looks like this:

```
$scope.yellowPages = {
   "question_id1": "rating1",
   "question_id2": "rating2"
}
```

with this you can easily access your questions without looping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this way just to update the existing value, since I only need 5 values to be present in array, so I'm checking only after 5 initial values are inserted. However I think this is not the most optimal way to achieve it, but this solved my problem.

```
if ($scope.yellowPages.length >= 5) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.yellowPages.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.yellowPages[i]["question_id"] == question_id) {
        $scope.yellowPages[i]["rating"] = rating;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    $scope.yellowPages.push({rating: rating, question_id: question_id});
  }
```